# Add an LED to indicate that "it's on"

Tags: led

I have a simplified circuit to power a 12 volt fridge. I would like to add an LED to show that the fridge has been turned on.
The issue is I just can't chuck in an LED because the wiring can run 10 amps.
So the question is how do I add an LED on the 10 amp line without burning out the LED?
Have added a simple drawing to show what I am trying to achieve.
Cheers Scott.
[image]

Comment: what does `fridge has been turned on` mean exactly?

Comment: `wiring can run 10 amps` is irrelevant ... `wiring has 12 V potential` is relevant

Answer (score 6):

Wire in an LED as shown here with the resistor in line with the LED. At 12V the resistor value of say 4.7K ohms should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt reply.  I assume the wire should be the same size as the wire that is going to the fridge.

Comment: @Scott You assume wrong. Current through the LED and resistor is tiny, only a few milliamps. The wires connecting them together, and to the power supply, may be much thinner than those connecting the 12V source to the fridge.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  Us civil earth guys always go for big. LOL.  Ive been wiring up 12 volts system/ dual batteries for years.  So we can keep drinks and food cool.  Some of my guys would like some indicator lights so they know what's running.  I'll solder on some "trigger wire" onto the 10amp wire.  Cheers

Comment: Solder the resistor to the 10A wire, then the thin wire to that. this will make any short-circuits in the indicator loop much less exciting.

Comment: @Scott You can just buy "12 volt LED indicator light" from most anywhere (including Amazon.) Google them up. They are cheap and easy to apply and the wiring is appropriate. The units are pretty and have mounting hardware included, too. As Michael indicates all you need to do is add the indicator ***after*** the switch that enables power to the unit(s), placing the LED indicator *"in parallel"* with the load, itself.